# jCarousel with hidden items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I'm using jCarousel to show of list of products available to select from certain conditions.
Conditions can hide/show items from ul that is used to create carousel.

In situations where there is many hidden items on list it is possible for user to scroll the list to blank page.

I'm wondering, if there's a easy solution to this? How tell jCarousel to use only visible items as count for calculating how many pages there are?
Thanks

Comment: Modify the carousel code to use the :visible pseudo-selector for the list items.

Comment: yeah, tried that. It looks like jCarousel after such modification removes elements from list that are exceeding length of visible items. So if we have 3 items visible, and 5 not, and we want to show 4 elements in the same time, jCarousel removes first of those fifth visible.